# Delete Command After Execute discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do i make my command delete from chat after executing in this code:

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.author.id != process.env.OWNERID)
        return message.channel.send("Only my developer can use this command...");
    const msg = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    if (!msg) return message.reply("Send something!");
    message.channel.send(msg);
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "send-message",
    description: "N/A",
    usage: "d!send-message [Message]",
    accessableby: "Bot Owners",
    aliases: []
};
```

like if i were to do " d!send-message discord.js help

how would i make "d!send-message discord.js help" delete from discord chat by the bot after executed?

Comment: after this code line `message.channel.send(msg);`, add `message.delete()`

Comment: You mark a question as solved by "accepting" the answer that helped you. Editing any part of your question, aside from clarifications, is counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.delete()` function

Here's an example for you:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if (message.author.id != process.env.OWNERID)
        return message.channel.send("Only my developer can use this command...");
    const msg = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    if (!msg) return message.reply("Send something!");
    message.channel.send(msg);
    message.delete()  // ** NEW LINE
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "send-message",
    description: "N/A",
    usage: "d!send-message [Message]",
    accessableby: "Bot Owners",
    aliases: []
};
```